# Getting information from multiple using MySQLI and be able to echo results

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

for the past few hours, I have been trying to find a simple method of while loop echoing information from multiple tables at once. I'd like to say I've not pulled all my hair out looking, but I have.

Here is one mysqli query to get the following fields from `CUSTOMER`

```
$tid = $_SESSION['user_id']; // "id" is 1 for example

$query = "SELECT * FROM `CUSTOMER` WHERE user_id = {$tid}";
$results = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo $row['user_id'] . "<br><br>";
echo $row['c_fname'] . "<br>";
echo $row['c_sname'] . "<br>";
};
```

Here is another mysqli query to get the following fields from `SALE`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `SALE` WHERE user_id = {$tid}";
$results = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo $row['s_date'] . "<br>";
echo $row['s_total'] . "<br>";
};
```

Could someone possibly show me how I can get both of these tables in one query so that echoing both tables information is possible at the same time instead of separately. I am not fussed how it is done, As long as it gets all from both tables for echoing purpose, that is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `LEFT JOIN` like this.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

And this is your code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `CUSTOMER` LEFT JOIN `SALE` ON `SALE`.user_id=`CUSTOMER`.user_id WHERE `SALE`.user_id={$tid}";
$results = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo $row['user_id'] . "<br><br>";
    echo $row['c_fname'] . "<br>";
    echo $row['c_sname'] . "<br>";
    echo $row['s_date'] . "<br>";
    echo $row['s_total'] . "<br>";
}
```

For more info read this,
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp
I hope this helps.

**EDITED**

This is for joining 3 tables,

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.column_name = table3.column_name;
```

In your code.

```
SELECT * FROM `CUSTOMER`
LEFT JOIN `SALE` ON `CUSTOMER`.user_id = `SALE`.user_id
LEFT JOIN `PRODUCTS` ON `CUSTOMER`.user_id = `PRODUCTS`.user_id
WHERE `SALE`.user_id={$tid};
```

As variable.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `CUSTOMER` LEFT JOIN `SALE` ON `CUSTOMER`.user_id = `SALE`.user_id LEFT JOIN `PRODUCTS` ON `CUSTOMER`.user_id = `PRODUCTS`.user_id WHERE `SALE`.user_id={$tid}";
```

Comment: Your code seems to be giving me a solid white page.

Comment: Ohh i forgot `;` in `$query` variable line. try it and tell me if there any other problem.

Comment: even with the changes, yours still doesn't seem to produce results like Somnath Sinha's suggestion.

Comment: So what is the problem now?

Comment: It isn't a while page anymore, it just doesn't display anything. output is blank.

Comment: Put this in your code and give me the output,
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Yours is now working with what seems to be the addition of " ` " around the table names. Say I was to add a third table. `PRODUCTS` for example, would that be hard to insert into the query?

Comment: I added the way to join 3 tables, Check out my answer. And it's a pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply join the tables to get your expected result as shown below.

```
$query = "SELECT c.user_id, c.c_fname, c.c_sname, s.s_date, s.s_total FROM `CUSTOMER` AS c INNER JOIN `SALE` AS s ON c.user_id = s.user_id WHERE c.user_id = {$tid}";
```

Joining 3 tables example

```
$query = "SELECT *
FROM `CUSTOMER` AS c
INNER JOIN `SALE` AS s ON c.user_id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN `PRODUCTS` AS p ON p.product_id = s.product_id
WHERE c.user_id = {$tid}";
```

Comment: Your code seems to be specifically targeting elements within the table. I am looking for select * specifically.

Comment: You can use * also, mine one is just an example

Comment: With using *, yours works perfectly, but how would I go about adding further tables?

Comment: Same way you can join multiple tables.
`SELECT * FROM ATAB AS a INNER JOIN BTAB AS b ON a.col1 = b.col2 INNER JOIN BTAB AS c ON a.col2 = c.col1` for example.

Comment: So say I was to add table "PRODUCTS" through user_id, how would that add into the query?

Comment: I can frame this example also for you, but before that, can you please explain what is your actual expectation?
Because whenever you write a JOIN query, you can use * to retrieve your column, but you have to specify joining conditions.

Comment: I am looking for a simple method to easily be able to echo from multiple tables at once. Your original answer, though it works with the two provided, I have not the slightest idea on how I would add a third for example.

Comment: Assuming `product_id` is the joining criteria between `SALES` and `PRODUCTS` table, `$query = "SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER AS c
INNER JOIN SALE AS s ON c.user_id = s.user_id
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS AS p ON p.product_id = s.product_id
WHERE c.user_id = {$tid}";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code and will help u solve Ur problem

```
$query = "SELECT C.*,S.* FROM CUSTOMER C,SALES S 
WHERE C.user_id={$tid}
and C.user_id=S.user_id;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo $row['C.user_id'] . "<br><br>";
echo $row['C.c_fname'] . "<br>";
echo $row['C.c_sname'] . "<br>";
echo $row['S.s_date'] . "<br>";
echo $row['S.s_total'] . "<br>";
};
```